# Forms/ submit buttons that direct to URL based on user input

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a form on a webpage:

```
<?php echo form_open('/search/processing'); ?>

<input type="text" name="query" size="50" />

    <input type="submit" name="1" value="1" /></br>
    <input type="submit" name="2" value="2" /></br>
    <input type="submit" name="3" value="3" /></br>

</form>
```

It goes to this controller function:

```
public function processing()
{
// redirects here based on user input and what submit button was pressed
}
```

I'm wondering is it possible to get rid of this function and simply redirect straight from the form based on what the user has entered?

Comment: your answer lies in javascript, this may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: Yes it is possible, Can you please elaborate it more, probably with some example?

Comment: Havent had time to try it, but if you need it in javascript, cant you use the onvalidate to alter the action url?  As i say, i havent tried it but that was what sprang to mind.  If you havent sorted it, ill try that out later this afternoon.

Comment: You can't override the controller's method but using `Javascript` you can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('formid').addEventListener('submit', function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            if(this[i].type == 'submit' &&
               this[i].value == 1) window.location.href = 'foo.com';
            else if( ... )
               ....
            else if( ... )
               ....
    }, false);
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure PHP, then:

```
if(isset($_POST['query']))
{
  switch($_POST['query'])
  {
    case 'hello': header('location: http://www.google.com'); break;
    case 'stack': header('location: http://www.ask.com'); break;
    case 'overflow': header('location: http://www.yahoo.com'); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is using `CodeIgniter framework` and don't want to use the controller to be invoked, this answer is not helpful in this case.

Comment: Other than using a tag, OP did not state this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved in the following:
Where the comments are, include redirect code, or a function call.

```
if (isset($_POST['query']) {
  $value = $_POST['query'];
  if ($value == 1) {
    //do something
  }
  if ($value == 2) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is using CodeIgniter framework and don't want to use the controller to be invoked, this answer is not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain javascript version of changing the form action, it may not be exactly what you want as you have 3 seperate buttons, but it maybe useful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
 {
     if ( document.forms.form.test1.checked )
     {
         document.forms.form.action = "http://google.com";
     }

     return true;
 }
</script>
<form name="form" action="a.html" onsubmit="return test()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="test1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Basically if you have the button checked it goes to google.com - else a.html